# The choice of key to keep track of functions already running in recursive calls

Tags: python, recursion

A function [`recursive_repr`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) in [`reprlib`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/reprlib.html#module-reprlib) module, introduced in Python 3.2, has the following  [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/reprlib.py):

```
def recursive_repr(fillvalue='...'):
    'Decorator to make a repr function return fillvalue for a recursive call'

    def decorating_function(user_function):
        repr_running = set()

        def wrapper(self):
            key = id(self), get_ident()
            if key in repr_running:
                return fillvalue
            repr_running.add(key)
            try:
                result = user_function(self)
            finally:
                repr_running.discard(key)
            return result

        # Can't use functools.wraps() here because of bootstrap issues
        wrapper.__module__ = getattr(user_function, '__module__')
        wrapper.__doc__ = getattr(user_function, '__doc__')
        wrapper.__name__ = getattr(user_function, '__name__')
        wrapper.__annotations__ = getattr(user_function, '__annotations__', {})
        return wrapper

    return decorating_function
```

The `key` identifying the specific `__repr__` function is set to be `(id(self), get_ident())`.

Why `self` itself wasn't used as a key?
And why [`get_ident`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.get_ident) was needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
a = []
b = []
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
a == b
```

This causes a stack overflow. But the algorithm needs to handle this case safely. If you put `self` into the set, it'll compare using `==` and the algorithm will fail. So we use `id(self)` instead which doesn't attempt to check for equality of the objects. We only care if it is the exact same object.

As for `get_indent`, consider what happens in this algorithm if two threads try to use the code at the same time. The `repr_running` set is shared between all the threads. But if multiple thread start adding and removing elements from that set, there is no telling what will happen. `get_ident()` is unique to the thread running it, so by using that with the key we know all threads will use different keys and be ok.

Comment: But `__repr__` is a function, so `repr_running` will be the set containing only functions, so there won't be the case where stack overflow may happen.

Comment: @ovgolovin, eh? I'm pretty sure other stuff then functions get stuck in the `repr_running` set.